# Subsetting data frame per date and integer values - R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very big dataset, here is an extract

```
> data
  UTC.Date UTC.Time sum           newdate
1 14/04/18 00:00:00 262 14/04/18 00:00:00
2 14/04/18 00:05:00 264 14/04/18 00:05:00
3 14/04/18 00:10:00 292 14/04/18 00:10:00
4 14/04/18 00:15:00 254 14/04/18 00:15:00
5 14/04/18 00:20:00 186 14/04/18 00:20:00
6 14/04/18 00:25:00 310 14/04/18 00:25:00
```

Basically, as you can see, I have an integer value in `data$sum` every 5 minutes (so, 288 records/day), for many days.

I would like to find out those days where there are no more than 12 records above a certain threshold (200, for example).

Furthermore, I would like to find out those periods about at least 1 week where this situation occur consecutively (in other words, at least 7 days where I have no more than 12 records above 200 in `data$sum` per day).

My first idea was to create a new column pasting date and time (`data$newdate`) and to use a filter based on this column, but I can't figure how to go on.

Any help? Hope I was clear

PS: as asked by @JDG I post here the dput()

```
    structure(list(UTC.Date = structure(c(195L, 195L, 195L, 195L, 
195L, 195L, 195L, 195L, 195L, 195L, 195L, 195L, 195L, 195L, 195L, 
195L, 195L, 195L, 195L, 195L), .Label = c("01/01/19", "01/02/19", 
"01/03/19", "01/04/19", "01/05/18", "01/05/19", "01/06/18", "01/06/19", 
"01/07/18", "01/07/19", "01/08/18", "01/09/18", "01/10/18", "01/11/18", 
"01/12/18", "02/01/19", "02/02/19", "02/03/19", "02/04/19", "02/05/18", 
"02/05/19", "02/06/18", "02/06/19", "02/07/18", "02/07/19", "02/08/18", 
"02/09/18", "02/10/18", "02/11/18", "02/12/18", "03/01/19", "03/02/19", 
"03/03/19", "03/04/19", "03/05/18", "03/05/19", "03/06/18", "03/06/19", 
"03/07/18", "03/07/19", "03/08/18", "03/09/18", "03/10/18", "03/11/18", 
"03/12/18", "04/01/19", "04/02/19", "04/03/19", "04/04/19", "04/05/18", 
"04/05/19", "04/06/18", "04/06/19", "04/07/18", "04/07/19", "04/08/18", 
"04/09/18", "04/10/18", "04/11/18", "04/12/18", "05/01/19", "05/02/19", 
"05/03/19", "05/04/19", "05/05/18", "05/05/19", "05/06/18", "05/06/19", 
"05/07/18", "05/07/19", "05/08/18", "05/09/18", "05/10/18", "05/11/18", 
"05/12/18", "06/01/19", "06/02/19", "06/03/19", "06/04/19", "06/05/18", 
"06/05/19", "06/06/18", "06/06/19", "06/07/18", "06/07/19", "06/08/18", 
"06/09/18", "06/10/18", "06/11/18", "06/12/18", "07/01/19", "07/02/19", 
"07/03/19", "07/04/19", "07/05/18", "07/05/19", "07/06/18", "07/06/19", 
"07/07/18", "07/07/19", "07/08/18", "07/09/18", "07/10/18", "07/11/18", 
"07/12/18", "08/01/19", "08/02/19", "08/03/19", "08/04/19", "08/05/18", 
"08/05/19", "08/06/18", "08/06/19", "08/07/18", "08/07/19", "08/08/18", 
"08/09/18", "08/10/18", "08/11/18", "08/12/18", "09/01/19", "09/02/19", 
"09/03/19", "09/04/19", "09/05/18", "09/05/19", "09/06/18", "09/06/19", 
"09/07/18", "09/07/19", "09/08/18", "09/09/18", "09/10/18", "09/11/18", 
"09/12/18", "10/01/19", "10/02/19", "10/03/19", "10/04/19", "10/05/18", 
"10/05/19", "10/06/18", "10/06/19", "10/07/18", "10/08/18", "10/09/18", 
"10/10/18", "10/11/18", "10/12/18", "11/01/19", "11/02/19", "11/03/19", 
"11/04/19", "11/05/18", "11/05/19", "11/06/18", "11/06/19", "11/07/18", 
"11/08/18", "11/09/18", "11/10/18", "11/11/18", "11/12/18", "12/01/19", 
"12/02/19", "12/03/19", "12/04/19", "12/05/18", "12/05/19", "12/06/18", 
"12/06/19", "12/07/18", "12/08/18", "12/09/18", "12/10/18", "12/11/18", 
"12/12/18", "13/01/19", "13/02/19", "13/03/19", "13/04/19", "13/05/18", 
"13/05/19", "13/06/18", "13/06/19", "13/07/18", "13/08/18", "13/09/18", 
"13/10/18", "13/11/18", "13/12/18", "14/01/19", "14/02/19", "14/03/19", 
"14/04/18", "14/04/19", "14/05/18", "14/05/19", "14/06/18", "14/06/19", 
"14/07/18", "14/08/18", "14/09/18", "14/10/18", "14/11/18", "14/12/18", 
"15/01/19", "15/02/19", "15/03/19", "15/04/18", "15/04/19", "15/05/18", 
"15/05/19", "15/06/18", "15/06/19", "15/07/18", "15/08/18", "15/09/18", 
"15/10/18", "15/11/18", "15/12/18", "16/01/19", "16/02/19", "16/03/19", 
"16/04/18", "16/04/19", "16/05/18", "16/05/19", "16/06/18", "16/06/19", 
"16/07/18", "16/08/18", "16/09/18", "16/10/18", "16/11/18", "16/12/18", 
"17/01/19", "17/02/19", "17/03/19", "17/04/18", "17/04/19", "17/05/18", 
"17/05/19", "17/06/18", "17/06/19", "17/07/18", "17/08/18", "17/09/18", 
"17/10/18", "17/11/18", "17/12/18", "18/01/19", "18/02/19", "18/03/19", 
"18/04/18", "18/04/19", "18/05/18", "18/05/19", "18/06/18", "18/06/19", 
"18/07/18", "18/08/18", "18/09/18", "18/10/18", "18/11/18", "18/12/18", 
"19/01/19", "19/02/19", "19/03/19", "19/04/18", "19/04/19", "19/05/18", 
"19/05/19", "19/06/18", "19/06/19", "19/07/18", "19/08/18", "19/09/18", 
"19/10/18", "19/11/18", "19/12/18", "20/01/19", "20/02/19", "20/03/19", 
"20/04/18", "20/04/19", "20/05/18", "20/05/19", "20/06/18", "20/06/19", 
"20/07/18", "20/08/18", "20/09/18", "20/10/18", "20/11/18", "20/12/18", 
"21/01/19", "21/02/19", "21/03/19", "21/04/18", "21/04/19", "21/05/18", 
"21/05/19", "21/06/18", "21/06/19", "21/07/18", "21/08/18", "21/09/18", 
"21/10/18", "21/11/18", "21/12/18", "22/01/19", "22/02/19", "22/03/19", 
"22/04/18", "22/04/19", "22/05/18", "22/05/19", "22/06/18", "22/06/19", 
"22/07/18", "22/08/18", "22/09/18", "22/10/18", "22/11/18", "22/12/18", 
"23/01/19", "23/02/19", "23/03/19", "23/04/18", "23/04/19", "23/05/18", 
"23/05/19", "23/06/18", "23/06/19", "23/07/18", "23/08/18", "23/09/18", 
"23/10/18", "23/11/18", "23/12/18", "24/01/19", "24/02/19", "24/03/19", 
"24/04/18", "24/04/19", "24/05/18", "24/05/19", "24/06/18", "24/06/19", 
"24/07/18", "24/08/18", "24/09/18", "24/10/18", "24/11/18", "24/12/18", 
"25/01/19", "25/02/19", "25/03/19", "25/04/18", "25/04/19", "25/05/18", 
"25/05/19", "25/06/18", "25/06/19", "25/07/18", "25/08/18", "25/09/18", 
"25/10/18", "25/11/18", "25/12/18", "26/01/19", "26/02/19", "26/03/19", 
"26/04/18", "26/04/19", "26/05/18", "26/05/19", "26/06/18", "26/06/19", 
"26/07/18", "26/08/18", "26/09/18", "26/10/18", "26/11/18", "26/12/18", 
"27/01/19", "27/02/19", "27/03/19", "27/04/18", "27/04/19", "27/05/18", 
"27/05/19", "27/06/18", "27/06/19", "27/07/18", "27/08/18", "27/09/18", 
"27/10/18", "27/11/18", "27/12/18", "28/01/19", "28/02/19", "28/03/19", 
"28/04/18", "28/04/19", "28/05/18", "28/05/19", "28/06/18", "28/06/19", 
"28/07/18", "28/08/18", "28/09/18", "28/10/18", "28/11/18", "28/12/18", 
"29/01/19", "29/03/19", "29/04/18", "29/04/19", "29/05/18", "29/05/19", 
"29/06/18", "29/06/19", "29/07/18", "29/08/18", "29/09/18", "29/10/18", 
"29/11/18", "29/12/18", "30/01/19", "30/03/19", "30/04/18", "30/04/19", 
"30/05/18", "30/05/19", "30/06/18", "30/06/19", "30/07/18", "30/08/18", 
"30/09/18", "30/10/18", "30/11/18", "30/12/18", "31/01/19", "31/03/19", 
"31/05/18", "31/05/19", "31/07/18", "31/08/18", "31/10/18", "31/12/18"
), class = "factor"), UTC.Time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L), .Label = c("00:00:00", "00:05:00", "00:10:00", "00:15:00", 
"00:20:00", "00:25:00", "00:30:00", "00:35:00", "00:40:00", "00:45:00", 
"00:50:00", "00:55:00", "01:00:00", "01:05:00", "01:10:00", "01:15:00", 
"01:20:00", "01:25:00", "01:30:00", "01:35:00", "01:40:00", "01:45:00", 
"01:50:00", "01:55:00", "02:00:00", "02:05:00", "02:10:00", "02:15:00", 
"02:20:00", "02:25:00", "02:30:00", "02:35:00", "02:40:00", "02:45:00", 
"02:50:00", "02:55:00", "03:00:00", "03:05:00", "03:10:00", "03:15:00", 
"03:20:00", "03:25:00", "03:30:00", "03:35:00", "03:40:00", "03:45:00", 
"03:50:00", "03:55:00", "04:00:00", "04:05:00", "04:10:00", "04:15:00", 
"04:20:00", "04:25:00", "04:30:00", "04:35:00", "04:40:00", "04:45:00", 
"04:50:00", "04:55:00", "05:00:00", "05:05:00", "05:10:00", "05:15:00", 
"05:20:00", "05:25:00", "05:30:00", "05:35:00", "05:40:00", "05:45:00", 
"05:50:00", "05:55:00", "06:00:00", "06:05:00", "06:10:00", "06:15:00", 
"06:20:00", "06:25:00", "06:30:00", "06:35:00", "06:40:00", "06:45:00", 
"06:50:00", "06:55:00", "07:00:00", "07:05:00", "07:10:00", "07:15:00", 
"07:20:00", "07:25:00", "07:30:00", "07:35:00", "07:40:00", "07:45:00", 
"07:50:00", "07:55:00", "08:00:00", "08:05:00", "08:10:00", "08:15:00", 
"08:20:00", "08:25:00", "08:30:00", "08:35:00", "08:40:00", "08:45:00", 
"08:50:00", "08:55:00", "09:00:00", "09:05:00", "09:10:00", "09:15:00", 
"09:20:00", "09:25:00", "09:30:00", "09:35:00", "09:40:00", "09:45:00", 
"09:50:00", "09:55:00", "10:00:00", "10:05:00", "10:10:00", "10:15:00", 
"10:20:00", "10:25:00", "10:30:00", "10:35:00", "10:40:00", "10:45:00", 
"10:50:00", "10:55:00", "11:00:00", "11:05:00", "11:10:00", "11:15:00", 
"11:20:00", "11:25:00", "11:30:00", "11:35:00", "11:40:00", "11:45:00", 
"11:50:00", "11:55:00", "12:00:00", "12:05:00", "12:10:00", "12:15:00", 
"12:20:00", "12:25:00", "12:30:00", "12:35:00", "12:40:00", "12:45:00", 
"12:50:00", "12:55:00", "13:00:00", "13:05:00", "13:10:00", "13:15:00", 
"13:20:00", "13:25:00", "13:30:00", "13:35:00", "13:40:00", "13:45:00", 
"13:50:00", "13:55:00", "14:00:00", "14:05:00", "14:10:00", "14:15:00", 
"14:20:00", "14:25:00", "14:30:00", "14:35:00", "14:40:00", "14:45:00", 
"14:50:00", "14:55:00", "15:00:00", "15:05:00", "15:10:00", "15:15:00", 
"15:20:00", "15:25:00", "15:30:00", "15:35:00", "15:40:00", "15:45:00", 
"15:50:00", "15:55:00", "16:00:00", "16:05:00", "16:10:00", "16:15:00", 
"16:20:00", "16:25:00", "16:30:00", "16:35:00", "16:40:00", "16:45:00", 
"16:50:00", "16:55:00", "17:00:00", "17:05:00", "17:10:00", "17:15:00", 
"17:20:00", "17:25:00", "17:30:00", "17:35:00", "17:40:00", "17:45:00", 
"17:50:00", "17:55:00", "18:00:00", "18:05:00", "18:10:00", "18:15:00", 
"18:20:00", "18:25:00", "18:30:00", "18:35:00", "18:40:00", "18:45:00", 
"18:50:00", "18:55:00", "19:00:00", "19:05:00", "19:10:00", "19:15:00", 
"19:20:00", "19:25:00", "19:30:00", "19:35:00", "19:40:00", "19:45:00", 
"19:50:00", "19:55:00", "20:00:00", "20:05:00", "20:10:00", "20:15:00", 
"20:20:00", "20:25:00", "20:30:00", "20:35:00", "20:40:00", "20:45:00", 
"20:50:00", "20:55:00", "21:00:00", "21:05:00", "21:10:00", "21:15:00", 
"21:20:00", "21:25:00", "21:30:00", "21:35:00", "21:40:00", "21:45:00", 
"21:50:00", "21:55:00", "22:00:00", "22:05:00", "22:10:00", "22:15:00", 
"22:20:00", "22:25:00", "22:30:00", "22:35:00", "22:40:00", "22:45:00", 
"22:50:00", "22:55:00", "23:00:00", "23:05:00", "23:10:00", "23:15:00", 
"23:20:00", "23:25:00", "23:30:00", "23:35:00", "23:40:00", "23:45:00", 
"23:50:00", "23:55:00"), class = "factor"), sum = c(262L, 264L, 
292L, 254L, 186L, 310L, 413L, 412L, 346L, 225L, 333L, 221L, 262L, 
214L, 203L, 213L, 208L, 211L, 231L, 240L), newdate = c("14/04/18 00:00:00", 
"14/04/18 00:05:00", "14/04/18 00:10:00", "14/04/18 00:15:00", 
"14/04/18 00:20:00", "14/04/18 00:25:00", "14/04/18 00:30:00", 
"14/04/18 00:35:00", "14/04/18 00:40:00", "14/04/18 00:45:00", 
"14/04/18 00:50:00", "14/04/18 00:55:00", "14/04/18 01:00:00", 
"14/04/18 01:05:00", "14/04/18 01:10:00", "14/04/18 01:20:00", 
"14/04/18 01:25:00", "14/04/18 01:30:00", "14/04/18 01:35:00", 
"14/04/18 01:40:00")), .Names = c("UTC.Date", "UTC.Time", "sum", 
"newdate"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you share a reproducible example? Kindly post the output of `dput(head(data, 20))`

Comment: Honestly I don't know how the output should be, maybe a simple vector where I can find the days with 12 or less values above 200

Comment: I think you misunderstood @JDG's request. Please execute `dput(head(data,20))` in your R session, and paste the result into your question.